# Does Java have a class for Java Bean standard handling?

Tags: java, javabeans

Does Java natively have a class for Java Bean standard handling? Say, I want to pass the field name and instance and get the getter, or setter, or value?

Comment: The methods in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html and the classes in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html should be able to provide this.  I'm not sure if there's a special class specifically for bean handling, but if there were, it would mostly be calls to the `Class` and `reflect` stuff.

Comment: Yes, I know you can get what I want by using reflection. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No, it doesn't; there's nothing magical about beans.

Comment: @Louis Except there is, with the Introspector and related classes.